# Added a new template file to a theme - get Call to undefined function error

Tags: themes, templates

I added a new file in the theme folder and it doesn't seem to be working properly.

The first line `get_header();` creates an error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header()` like it's not seeing any includes.

Any ideas why that happens? All files in the same theme folder work just fine except this one.

Comment: What Theme are you using? What file did you add to the Theme? How/in what context will WordPress use/render this new file?

Comment: I am using a custom theme and I added a file called "sendEmail.php" which takes data from an AJAX call and sends an email using `wp_mail()`.

Comment: I think the issue is that you're trying to use WordPress functions *outside the context* of WordPress. Just a suggestion, but you might get more effective answers if you re-phrased your question as **how to take data from an AJAX call and send an email using `wp_mail()`**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are prbebaly using wordpress elements outside the loop
and since its a file ou dont access directly from wordpress
structure but a file you created yourself you should include

```
<?php
require_once("../../../wp-load.php");
?>
```

Above the doc type opening tag in sendEMail.php file..

Comment: [Don’t include wp-load, please.](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/) My `wp-content` directory may be on a different directory outside of the WordPress directory. Good luck finding `wp-load.php`! :)

Comment: i see... does that "moving files around" really happens? i havent noticed that wp-load.php moved since 2.1 (which is the first verstion i installed) - not ideal solution for sure but real easy for a single, few files which you just want to put into your design no?

Comment: Yes, it happens. I have fixed performance problems for some clients, and part of the job was it to move the `wp-content` to another, cookieless domain. Themes or plugin searching for `wp-load.php` would just die then.